# antispam and RFC status codes

Tags: email, smtp, rfc822, spam-prevention

I am running a proxy antispam in my mailserver (ASSP 2.4).

If a remote spammer email is blocked, the antispam permits to configure a reply with a

- 554 5.7.1 Message blocked due to spam content in the message
  or
- by sending a "false"  '250 OK' instead of SMTP error code '554 5.7.1'.

Two questions please ;

a) If I use the '250 OK' solution , am I breaking some some rule in the 
   Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (RFC 821 and RFC 5321) ?

b) Which is better and recommended and why ; "554 5.7.1" or "250 OK" ?

Thank you, Graziano

Comment: Better for what?  The 250 is a violation of the spirit, if not the letter, of the protocol, yes, if you know you are not actually going to deliver the message; but accepting and dropping on the floor reveals less to the spammer -- an explicit blocking note tells them something went wrong, and may inspire them to try harder.

Comment: Not a programming question; nominating for migration to http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to section 3.3 of [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) once you, the receiver, send a `250 OK` to the sender it means the reciever has successful stored the message. Further according to section 4.2.4 of RFC 532 responding to `<CRLF>.<CRLF>` with a positive code (`2yx`) you accept responsibility for delivery of the message. You can also find that a response of `5yz` to the `DATA` verb is accepted (with a `354`) is appropriate when "[...]the server determines that the message should be rejected for policy or other reasons."

So to follow RFC you should likely issue a `5yz` response if you determine a message to be spam. But no one polices this. If you configure your mail server to go against RFC you will still receive emails (especailly since you are waiting until the `DATA` phase to *break* the protocol, the sender cannot *unsend* the message).

However if you are willing to classify a message as spam you have then identified someone abusing the SMTP protocol so who cares what you do they are a dirty *spammer*? What if it is a false positive and the sender thinks you got their email when you in fact did not because you discarded it for being spam? Spam filters are often wrong.

No one is going to come to you and *report* you for not following SMTP protocol, this is because the RFC's **are written to be interpreted**. However you should configure your mail server to be some what friendly to a sender who is legitimate but is falsely identified as having sent you spam, so they can communicate the issue to you.